# how to add value to A tag parameter when using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I get data from DB using AJAX

actual value is `val.id = 25`

this is not passing value,

```
<a href="{{route('OpenMyAdd',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>'+val.id+']) }}" class="" data-id="'+val.id+'">edit</a>
```

but I change code like this ,

```
<a href="{{route('OpenMyAdd',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>'25']) }}" class="" data-id="'+val.id+'">edit</a>
```

its passing,

how I can correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below one?

```
<a href="{{route('OpenMyAdd',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>"'+val.id+'"]) }}" class="" data-id="'+val.id+'">edit</a>
```

Comment: As per the katsarov mentioned, I think it will require to change the behavior of data loading. For example, load the id on page load with PHP or generate the href URL in javascript format

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass javascript variable to php code. Technically `val.id` doesn't even exists when the code is generated.

Check Ziggy package https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy. It allows you to use your routes in Javascript almost the same way as you will use it in php.

**Bonus:** I see you are using app()->getLocale() on your route and I suppose you are doing it for every route you call. Using default values can save you some time. Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#default-values
They also work in Ziggy.